# upgrading a project from vs 2008 to 2010 loses generated code in service reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, web-services, visual-studio-2010

I have a project that I'm upgrading from 2008 to 2010.
My problem is with the code being generated by a service reference. Any classes used in the Reference.cs are given by their full name according to the reference

**The difference results in a 'cannot convert from foo.Data.MtkBaseRequest to foo.WebServicesClient.ModelDataService.MtkBaseRequest'**

So I have the old code

```
namespace foo  
{  
  public abstract class MtkBaseRequest{}  
}
```

And this code being called

```
List<MtkBaseRequest> newList = new List<MtkBaseRequest>(requestArray);  
this.DataAccessWebService.doStuff(newList);
```

but this is the method it means to call(which is generated)

```
public void doStuff(System.Collections.Generic.List<foo.WebServicesClient.ModelDataService.MtkBaseRequest> requests)
```

So what's happening is that the namespace no longer matches for the class which should be the same.  In the code generated by VS 2008 the method being called is:

```
public void doStuff(System.Collections.Generic.List<foo.Data.MtkBaseRequest> requests)
```

Is there a work-around, or something I can do to get the code generating properly?

BTW: the project this is in is called WebServicesClient, the service reference is ModelDataService

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it, turns out there were some assemblies hanging around in the GAC.
stupid GAC